# ORDER BY lower case of output column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-9.1

I'm able to run this Postgres query without any issue:

```
select
(select product_types.name from product_types
 where product_types.id = products.product_type_id) AS product_type_name
 from products
order by product_type_name
```

But when I tried to order by lower case it doesn't work:

```
select
(select product_types.name from product_types
 where product_types.id = products.product_type_id) AS product_type_name
 from products
order by lower(product_type_name)
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "product_type_name" does not exist
LINE 4: order by lower(product_type_name)
                       ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "product_type_name" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 156
```

Can someone please shed me some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [manual page on `SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

> Each expression can be the name or ordinal number of an output column
> (`SELECT` list item), or it can be an arbitrary expression formed from
> input-column values.

You were trying to order by an expression formed from an **output**-column, which is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

At first sight, your first query could be rewritten just this way:

```
select pt.name product_type_name from product_types pt
join products p on pt.id = p.product_type_id
order by pt.name
```

Then, ordering with the `lower` function would mean just changing the order by to:

```
order by lower(pt.name)
```

Comment: Minor side note: Postgres discourages [omitting the keyword `AS` for *column* aliases](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#AEN80734) (but not for table aliases).

Comment: Probably it's worth mentioning that you could add index as well `CREATE INDEX idx_sth ON products (lower(name));`